# Deauth not working on a certain network and I want to understand why

Tags: network, protocols

I've done some research for the past hour but I can't find a definitive answer to what is happening.

So I use a AWUS036NHA, put it in monitor mode, sniff everything, then sniff the AP I want to do the deauth attack on, **I don't see any clients**, I'm like "OK maybe it's just some type of encryption or protocol I'm not aware of, no worry I will just do a 'global' deauth attack", then I launch the deauth attack with aircrack. I've tried every syntax flavor possible but none of the clients are disconnecting, I've even tried with the mac address of my phone that is connected to the AP.

The deauth attack worked on other networks but I can't figure out why it doesnt work on this one.

**Then I noticed that the network I'm attacking is handling 2.4 and 5ghz.** So I thought maybe that the problem is that my chipset can't cover both 2.4 and 5 so the network can just get away with the attack? I've also read that the **IEEE 802.11w amendment/protocol** can make deauth attacks useless but it's mostly used on enterprise networks?

I just want to understand why the attack doenst work and how I can check what is the problem instead of just abandoning.
Thank you and sorry for this beginner question.

Answer (score 1):

The wireless card you listed supports 2.4GHz. If the target network and devices are on 5GHz, you will not be able to see or touch them without obtaining different hardware.

802.11w is not used very widely, and even where it is used, it does a relatively poor job of preventing layer 2 attacks.

Comment: So even tho the AP is on both 2.4 and 5ghz just the fact that it is also on 5ghz makes my wireless adapter unable to see the AP's clients and launch deauth attacks against it?

Comment: @okaz The 2.4GHz and 5GHz networks are separate, so clients will only be using one of the bands at a time, based on signal strength and configuration etc. It's a little surprising that none of your devices are using 2.4, but you could likely try to verify by forcing a device to connect over 2.4.

Comment: I will try, thanks for your replies !

Comment: 802.11w can prevent basic deauth attacks (where an actual deauth frame is transmitted). It just can't protect from jamming or intentional interference.